# How to search for substrings in a long string and create a list in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring

I have a long string:

```
query = "PREFIX pht: <http://datalab.rwth-aachen.de/vocab/pht/>
         PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

         SELECT ?Age, ?SexTypes, ?Chest_Pain_Type, ?trestbpsD, ?cholD, 
                    ?Fasting_Glucose_Level, ?Resting_ECG_Type, ?thalachD, 
                    ?Exercise_Induced_Angina, ?oldpeakD, ?caD, ?Slope, ?Thallium_Scintigraphy, ?Diagnosis
                      WHERE {?URI a sct:125676002. }"
```

Now I need to create a list consisting all the substrings that start with '?'. So the list should look like as follows:

```
schema = ['Age', 'Sex', 'Chest_Pain_Type', 'Trestbps', 'Chol', 'Fasting_Glucose_Level', 'Resting_ECG_Type', 'ThalachD', 
             'Exercise_Induced_Angina', 'OldpeakD', 'CaD', 'Slope', 'Thallium_Scintigraphy', 'Diagnosis']
```

I tried with `str.startswith(str, beg=0,end=len(string))`

But it's not working as I expected. How can do it in Python?

Comment: Why is ?URI not in the result?

Comment: vbar, nice catch! Actually, I don't need the ?URI. I wanted to explain but later on thought it will increase the complexity of the question.

Comment: Yes, it rather does increase the complexity... :-) Regular expression can find all words starting with '?' (see below), but if you want to skip some of them depending on a larger context, you'll need some more steps...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using regex:

```
import re
query = """PREFIX pht: <http://datalab.rwth-aachen.de/vocab/pht/>
         PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

         SELECT ?Age, ?SexTypes, ?Chest_Pain_Type, ?trestbpsD, ?cholD, 
                    ?Fasting_Glucose_Level, ?Resting_ECG_Type, ?thalachD, 
                    ?Exercise_Induced_Angina, ?oldpeakD, ?caD, ?Slope, ?Thallium_Scintigraphy, ?Diagnosis
                      WHERE {?URI a sct:125676002. }"""

#print re.findall("\?\w+", query)
print([i.replace("?", "") for i in re.findall("\?\w+", query)])
```

**Output:**

```
['Age', 'SexTypes', 'Chest_Pain_Type', 'trestbpsD', 'cholD', 'Fasting_Glucose_Level', 'Resting_ECG_Type', 'thalachD', 'Exercise_Induced_Angina', 'oldpeakD', 'caD', 'Slope', 'Thallium_Scintigraphy', 'Diagnosis', 'URI']
```

Comment: thanks so much for saving my day! Sorry to bug but what if I want all the occurrences before the 'WHERE'? Can we somehow limit this? I am pretty new to Python.

Comment: Sure. You can trim the query string to exclude content after 'WHERE'. Ex:  query = query[:query.find("WHERE")]

Comment: Hi Rakesh, that worked perfectly! I already accepted the answer but since I don't have enough reputation so probably is not getting reflected.

Comment: Sorry, I now did! I'm pretty new to StackOverflow too. Thanks :)